# Transpose CSV data vertical to horizontal by productid

Tags: php, csv, transpose

I have a csv file online which needs te be transposed by php because this needs to be done every hour (cronjobs).

I use this csv to import products into opencart with 'csv-import' module from karapuz.

My current csv looks like this:

```
ProductID;ImageUrl;Sequence;LastUpdate
6867;[urllink0];0;19-08-2013
6867;[urllink1];1;19-08-2013
6867;[urllink2];2;20-03-2012
6867;[urllink3];0;19-08-2013
6867;[urllink4];1;19-08-2013
6867;[urllink5];2;19-08-2013
6867;[urllink6];3;20-03-2012
6867;[urllink7];4;20-03-2012
6867;[urllink8];2;20-03-2012
6867;[urllink9];0;19-08-2013
6867;[urllink10];1;20-03-2012
8352;[urllink11];0;19-03-2013
8352;[urllink12];1;20-03-2012
9970;[urllink13];0;19-08-2013
9970;[urllink14];1;20-03-2012
9970;[urllink15];0;19-08-2013
9970;[urllink16];1;19-08-2013
9970;[urllink17];2;20-03-2012
9970;[urllink18];3;20-03-2012
9970;[urllink19];0;19-03-2013
9970;[urllink20];0;19-08-2013
9970;[urllink21];1;19-08-2013
9970;[urllink22];2;20-03-2012
9970;[urllink23];3;20-03-2012
9970;[urllink24];5;20-03-2012
9970;[urllink25];6;20-03-2012
```

...................... 19000 lines

So every image for a certain product is put in rows.

For my import script, the csv should look like: (1 product per row)

```
productid;main image;additional images;
6867;[urllink0];[urllink1]:::[urllink2]:::.........;
8352;[urllink11];[urllink12];
9970;[urllink13];[urllink14]:::[urllink15]:::[urllink16]..........;
```

additional images are in 1 cell, devided by ':::'.

So rows should be transposed to columns, but the amount (sequence) of images is variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried, or are you just hoping someone will write the code for you?

Comment: If this is to match a database table definition, then you should really normalize your database table structures

Comment: Apart from that, totally unclear what the `:::` in your desired example output are supposed to mean. Neither does their placement seem to follow any specific rule or pattern, nor do they make sense in a CSV context.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The Karapuz import module can handle 2 ways for images. 1st is the main image and needs to be a single url. 2nd are additional images which need to be in 1 cell, devided by ::: (configurable in the module)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly all you are trying to do is change the format of your CSV file so it can be imported into an import friendly format for the 'csv-import' module from karapuz.

You'll need to parse the CSV and then rewrite it in the other format. Try this for parsing the CSV file and putting the values into an array. From here, all you would need to do is rewrite the CSV file in the new format. Hope this helps:

```
 $pid,$prods =array();
 $file = fopen('remove.csv', 'r');
 while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
     print_r($line);
     $pid =  explode(";",$line[0]);
     $prods[$pid[0]][] = $pid[1];
 }
 fclose($file);


 print_r($prods) // outputs below:
 [6867] => Array
    (
        [0] => [urllink0]
        [1] => [urllink1]
        [2] => [urllink2]
        [3] => [urllink3]
        [4] => [urllink4]
        [5] => [urllink5]
        [6] => [urllink6]
        [7] => [urllink7]
        [8] => [urllink8]
        [9] => [urllink9]
        [10] => [urllink10]
    )

[8352] => Array
    (
        [0] => [urllink11]
        [1] => [urllink12]
    )

[9970] => Array
    (
        [0] => [urllink13]
        [1] => [urllink14]
        [2] => [urllink15]
        [3] => [urllink16]
        [4] => [urllink17]
        [5] => [urllink18]
        [6] => [urllink19]
        [7] => [urllink20]
        [8] => [urllink21]
        [9] => [urllink22]
        [10] => [urllink23]
        [11] => [urllink24]
        [12] => [urllink25]
    )
```

Comment: This looks promising. Could you tell me also how to put these values into the csv line? Like "6867";[urllink0];[urllink1];... Putting multiple urls into one cell devided by ::: is no problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks Ricky! I am nearly there.

Right now I am trying this

```
$filename1='basimage1.csv';
$filename2='basimage2.csv';

//$fp = fopen($filename2, 'w'); 

$pid = array();
$prods = array();
$file = fopen($filename1, 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        $pid =  explode(";",$line[0]);
        $prods[$pid[0]][] = $pid[1];
    }
fclose($file);

$delimiter=';';
$devider=':::';

foreach ($prods as $line) {

    //If 5 images -> 1 main image + 4 additional images devided by ':::'
    if ($line[4]) {
        $csvline = $line[0] . $delimiter . $line[1] . $devider . $line[2] . $devider . $line[3] . $devider . $line[4] . $delimiter;     
    }

    //If 4 images -> 1 main image + 3 additional images devided by ':::'
    elseif ($line[3]) {
        $csvline = $line[0] . $delimiter . $line[1] . $devider . $line[2] . $devider . $line[3] . $delimiter;       
    }

    //If 3 images -> 1 main image + 2 additional images devided by ':::'
    elseif ($line[2]) {
        $csvline = $line[0] . $delimiter . $line[1] . $devider . $line[2] . $delimiter;     
    }

    //If 2 images -> 1 main image + 1 additional image
    elseif ($line[1]) {
        $csvline = $line[0] . $delimiter . $line[1] . $delimiter;       
    }

    //If 1 images -> 1 main image 
    elseif ($line[3]) {
        $csvline = $line[0] . $delimiter;       
    }

echo $csvline . '<br>';

}
```

What i need is getting the productid (in example 6867) back from the array, which are the subkeys.The Array created is now:

```
Array
 (
[6867] => Array
  (
    [0] => [urllink1] ....
  )
 .............
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the goal with following code:

```
//include settings for url and credentials
include 'config.php';

//Rico Computers Download script for BAS
$filename1='basimage1.csv';
$filename2='basimage2.csv';
$delimiter=';';
$devider=':::';

echo 'Downloading Bas CSV ... ';
file_put_contents ($filename1, file_get_contents($basurlimage));

echo 'OK<br>';
echo filesize($filename1) . ' bytes.<br>';

echo '<br>';

echo 'Editing Downloaded CSV ...<br>';

//open the destination file
$fp = fopen($filename2, 'w'); 

//for counting processed lines
$i=1;

//Output to Screen Table
echo '<table colspan=3 border=1>'; 

$pid = array();
$prods = array();
$file = fopen($filename1, 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
        $pid =  explode(";",$line[0]);
        $prods[$pid[0]][] = $pid[1];


    }
fclose($file);

 foreach ($prods as $product_id => $line) {

//If 5 images -> 1 main image + 4 additional images devided by ':::'
if ($line[4]) {
    $mainimage = $line[0];
    $additionalimages = $line[1] . $devider . $line[2] . $devider . $line[3] . $devider . $line[4];     
}

//If 4 images -> 1 main image + 3 additional images devided by ':::'
elseif ($line[3]) {
    $mainimage = $line[0];
    $additionalimages = $line[1] . $devider . $line[2] . $devider . $line[3];       
}

//If 3 images -> 1 main image + 2 additional images devided by ':::'
elseif ($line[2]) {
    $mainimage = $line[0];
    $additionalimages = $line[1] . $devider . $line[2];     
}

//If 2 images -> 1 main image + 1 additional image
elseif ($line[1]) {
    $mainimage = $line[0];
    $additionalimages = $line[1];       
}

//If 1 images -> 1 main image 
elseif ($line[0]) {
    $mainimage = $line[0];
        //Add Extra Header for new Column  
        if ($product_id == 'ProductID') { 
           $additionalimages = 'Additional Images'; 
           } else {
            $additionalimages = ''; 
        }   
}



fputcsv($fp,array($product_id, $mainimage, $additionalimages),$delimiter);

//Create Output 
echo '<tr>';    
echo '<td>' . $product_id . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $mainimage . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $additionalimages . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';   

flush();
ob_flush();
ob_end_flush();

$i++;

}

//close source and destination files
fclose($fp);

?>

</table>

<br>
<?php
echo '<br>Processed ' . $filename2 . ' to ' . filesize($filename2) . ' bytes.</td></tr>';
echo 'Lines processed: ' . $i . '</br>';
?>
```